# DefaultPickerStyle not working in Xcode 11 beta 6 swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

After upgrade to Xcode 11 beta 6, DefaultPicker is behaving like a wheelPicker

```
   var colors = ["Mumbai", "Delhi", "Chennai", "Hyderabad"]
   @State private var selectedColor = 0

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Picker(selection: $selectedColor, label: Text("Please choose a city")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< colors.count) {
               Text(self.colors[$0])
            }.pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I wanted single list row that navigates into a new list of possible options[Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuA9n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue added the picker inside Form, here the final code

```
   @State private var selectedColor = 0

   var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
          Picker(selection: $selectedColor, label: Text("Please choose a city")) {
              ForEach(0 ..< colors.count) {
                 Text(self.colors[$0])
              }.pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
          }
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are exactly trying to achieve but I guess you want to use segement picker.

replace

```
DefaultPickerStyle()
```

with

```
SegmentedPickerStyle()
```